# android : Is it possible to inherit from MainActivity class?

Tags: java, android, inheritance, findviewbyid

I started learning Java and `Android Development` just a week ago and I have a couple of basic things that I'd want to know.

The functioning of my app is that it has 10 buttons and each of them is disabled after it has been clicked once. If a total of 5 buttons have been clicked, then all the buttons must be disabled.
I didn't use a button array, but I want to know why this doesn't work.
(all necessary imports have been made)

> The `MainActivity` class goes like this:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    StartText();
}

Class1 c1object = new Class1();

TextView textobj;
Button Button1,Button2,Button3,Button4 /* similarly for the other 6 buttons*/ ;

public void StartText(){
    textobj = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
    textobj.setText("No Button has been clicked");
}

public void Click1(View view)
{
    Button1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    c1object.disablebutton(Button1,textobj,1);

}
public void Click2(View view)
{
    Button2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
    c1object.disablebutton(Button2,textobj,2);
}
public void Click3(View view)
{
    Button3 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button3);
    c1object.disablebutton(Button3,textobj,3);
}

public void Click4(View view)
{
    Button4 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button4);
    c1object.disablebutton(Button4,textobj,4);

}
// Similarly for 6 more buttons

}
```

> `Class1` is this:

```
public class Class1 {

Class2 c2object = new Class2();

private int Clickcount=0;

public void disablebutton(Button b, TextView t, int i) {
    b.setEnabled(false);
    String str = Integer.toString(i);
    t.setText("You clicked button: " + str);
    Clickcount++;
    if(Clickcount==5)
        c2object.disableAll();
}
}
```

> and finally, `Class2` goes like this:

```
public class Class2 {

MainActivity mainobject = new MainActivity();

public void disableAll(){

    mainobject.Button1.setEnabled(false);
    mainobject.Button2.setEnabled(false);
    mainobject.Button3.setEnabled(false);
    mainobject.Button4.setEnabled(false);
    //Similarly for the other 6 buttons

}

}
```

If I run this my app launches but a white screen is shown and the app closes.

After several tries, I realized that it always happens when I created an object of the `MainActivity` class.
I even tried inheriting the `MainActivity` but the result was the same.

I also tried changing `Class2` to this:

```
public class Class2 {

public void disableAll(){

    Button b1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    b1.setEnabled(false);
//Similarly for the other 9 buttons

}

}
```

I noticed that I can't use `findViewById` here.

These are the things I'd like to know:

1. Can we inherit from or create an object of `MainActivity`?
2. Why can't I use `findViewById` from another class apart from `MainActivity`?
3. What do I do to disable all the buttons after `Clickcount==5`?
4. You've seen my way of coding. Any practices that I need to follow? Any other suggestions to make my way of coding better?

Thank you for your help in advance!

Comment: For disabling the button, have an if statement where if (Clickcount == 5) { myButton.setEnabled(false); } and do that for as many buttons as you need. Also I wouldn't recommend structuring your code around creating instances of the MainActivity class. If you need to make instances of an object, create another class to do so. I'm not sure about the findViewById part though.

Comment: That's pretty much what I did. The problem is that I can't access myButton from this class without creating an object of MainActivity. But doing so is making my app crash.

Comment: You could try making MainActivity static and put all the disable buttons code in a static method in MainActivity. Just so you don't have to instantiate. What errors do you get when it crashes?

Comment: Since you're new, I'll go ahead and say that `new Activity()` (or its descendants) never should be called as that doesn't properly initialize the lifecycle of that Activity

Comment: "You could try making MainActivity static" **WHAT**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot instantiate an `Activity` class via its constructor. So you wont be able to write `MainActivity mainObject = new MainActivity()`. You still wouldn't want to do this however even if it were possible, as you would be creating a new instance of `MainActivity`, whereas you want to conduct operations on the buttons in the *existing* `MainActivity`.

One way around this would be to supply your `MainActivity` as an argument i neither your method or constructor. I.e.

```
class ClassTwo {

    private MainActivity activity;

    ClassTwo(MainActivity activity) {
        this.activity = activity;
    }

    void disableAll() {
        activity.btn1.setEnabled(false);
        //etc...
    }

}
```

Personally though I think passing in an `Activity` here is overkill, when all you want to do is act on the buttons. So, you could either pass the buttons as a constructor argument instead of the activity:

```
ClassTwo(Button[] btns) {
    this.btns = btns;
}
```

Or, you could pass in an `interface`. Or you could just consider supplying the `Button`s as an argument in the method, rather than storing them in an instance variable (I'd probably go for this):

```
class ClassTwo {

    ClassTwo(){} //Default, empty constructor

    void disableAll(Button[] btns) {
        for (Button btn : btns) {
            btn.setEnabled(false);
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to initialize the Buttons with (findViewByID(R.id.button) and add

```
setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
@Override
public void onClick(View v){ // action} 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can create Class2 object like this :

```
public Class2(MainActivity mainactivity){
    this.mainobject =mainactivity;
}
```

then In MainActivity's onCreate

```
Class2  class2=new Class2(MainActivity.this);
```

when you want find Button in Class2 ,you can use

```
mainobject.getCurrentView().findviewByID()
```